# Input populated with ajax return value set to null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a hidden form field that I'm populating with the return value of an ajax request.

`return value(result)` is not `null` but the hidden field's value is set to `null`.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id_city, new { @id = "hidMyModelid_city" })

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#MyCombo').change(function () {

        var str = document.getElementById('Mycombo').value;
        var str1 = str.split(", ", 1).toString();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'someaction',
            data: {
                countryy: str1
            },
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#hidMyModelid_city').val(result);
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't see the code where you seem to check for the value of the hidden field

Comment: May want to step through it in a debugger to see what's going on.  The code seems correct.

Comment: I don't think `id` is one of the values that has to be escaped with `@`.  Are you sure the hidden field has the right id.

Comment: What does "result" contains in the success callback?If you get the expected result, have you checked the rendered html to make sure that is the id of your hidden field and there are no multiple fields with that id? Also, if you receive an error and are returning a json from the server, double check that you have added the AllowGet flag as in `return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` (because you are sending an ajax GET request)

Comment: result contain a long number , as you see i put  alert(result) and it shows i get expected result.i just a one hiddenfor field and it's name is hidMyModelid_city .when i save data in data base , column id_city is null .